# Saving JSON data from server to recycler view shows only last JSON item

Tags: php, android, json, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to fetch data from my server and store it in recycler view. The code is correct and error free. The application runs, but it shows only last JSON item. I dont know what is wrong in my code. Below is the code for my activity:

```
public class Under8ClubSchedule extends AppCompatActivity {

public ProgressBar progressBar;
private static final String URL="http://prasaurus.com/conn_u8_club_schedule.php";
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

private List<Schedule_Items> listItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_under8_club_schedule);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pb);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.u8_club_schedule);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new Adapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    loadRecyclerViewData();

}

private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
                if(success == 1) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("under8_club_schedule");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject_current = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Schedule_Items schedule_items = new Schedule_Items(
                                jsonObject_current.getString("team_one"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("team_two"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("score"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("league_name"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("date"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("time"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("location")
                        );
                        listItems.add(schedule_items);
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

}

This code is for my adapter class file:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Schedule_Items> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Schedule_Items> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.schedule_orientation,parent,false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Schedule_Items schedule_items = listItems.get(position);

        holder.textView_team_name1.setText(schedule_items.getTeam_name1());
        holder.textView_team_name2.setText(schedule_items.getTeam_name2());
        holder.textView_score.setText(schedule_items.getScore());
        holder.textView_league_name.setText(schedule_items.getLeague_name());
        holder.textView_date.setText(schedule_items.getDate());
        holder.textView_time.setText(schedule_items.getTime());
        holder.textView_location.setText(schedule_items.getLocation());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textView_team_name1;
        public TextView textView_team_name2;
        public TextView textView_score;
        public TextView textView_league_name;
        public TextView textView_date;
        public TextView textView_time;
        public TextView textView_location;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView_team_name1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.team_name1);
            textView_team_name2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.team_name2);
            textView_score = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.score);
            textView_league_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.league_name);
            textView_date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            textView_time = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            textView_location = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);

        }
    }
```

I unable find what's wrong, everything looks good to me still only one item is visible, when I run this activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines should be called inside onCreate() and called after `listItems = new ArrayList<>();`

```
adapter = new Adapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and create a function inside adapter like this

```
public void setData(Arraylist<Schedule_Items> items){
this.listItems = items;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call this function like this.

```
             for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject_current = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Schedule_Items schedule_items = new Schedule_Items(
                                jsonObject_current.getString("team_one"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("team_two"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("score"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("league_name"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("date"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("time"),
                                jsonObject_current.getString("location")
                        );
                        listItems.add(schedule_items);
                    }
                }
         adapter.setData(listItems);
```

Comment: I did add `setData` function inside adapter but unable to call that function in activity. :\

Comment: Call adapter.setData and make setData as public static

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` cannot be referenced from static context. I tried calling it directly but I'm only getting the last JSON item in the array not the whole array

Answer (score 1):

You must call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Its working but showing only the last JSON entry, it is not showing all the data

Comment: Are you sure about number of items you received?

Comment: I've 2 items in my JSON file. U can check it from the URL provided in the code

Comment: Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Your wellcome ;-)